# Typeahead: why it is send request to the server after event $typeahead.select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead.js, angular-strap

Typeahead sending the request to the server with the selected value.
I think it is not necessary, how it prevent?

[Example Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bRRYgn874KwlnFIqZeor?p=preview)

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Address <small>(async via maps.googleapis.com)</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedAddress" data-animation="am-flip-x" ng-options="address as address for address in getAddress($viewValue)" template="a_template.html" placeholder="Enter address" bs-typeahead>
  </div>
  <div>
    selectedAddress: {{ selectedAddress }}
  </div>
</form>
```

--js

```
$scope.getAddress = function(viewValue) {
  var params = {address: viewValue, sensor: false};
  return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {params: params})
  .then(function(res) {
    angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(o) {
      o.label = o.formatted_address;
    });
    console.log(res.data.results)
    return res.data.results;
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you consider rewording?  What exactly are you trying to prevent?  Unnecessary calls to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Use typeahead-min-length and typeahead-wait-ms.  For example

```
      <input typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-wait-ms="1000" ....
```

Calls will not be made to your function until AT LEAST 3 characters are typed in and there has been a pause of 1000 ms. IE the user stops typing for that long. Play with the values as you wish to help minimize the number of calls that are made.